# How to run react native app on physical device as I have use npx expo start command but it's giving the below error

Tags: react-native

```
Error: Exception occurred while executing 'list':
java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150
 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:14888 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:4802 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:3510
        at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:2672)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14888)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:4802)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3510)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:969)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:865)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runList(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:724)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:226)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:7038)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1085)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:903)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4962)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:7022)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

How to solve the above error and successfully run app on physical device(android).

Comment: I have same problem, found a solution on 'Sansung' phisical device deleteting secure folder as you can see here...
[link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250553)